# Drupal Mysql SSL Connections

Tags: database, ssl

Cannot seem to find solid literature on using mysql-ssl connections with either Drupal 6 or Drupal 7. Piece of cake with wordpress. Is this a possibility, if not why?

Comment: Wow! Really? What is this 3rd grade? For the record I wasn't "comparing", I have a task at hand to make a bunch of sites - wordpress and drupal - work with mysql-ssl connections. Was just pointing out that I was able to get things working with wp.

Comment: @ram4nd That's not really what downvotes are for. If you think the question is of poor quality or unlikely to be useful to the site then you should downvote it, not because you disagree with a perceived comparison between Drupal and Wordpress. Personally I think it's a pretty good question, documentation is pretty scarce on the matter

Answer (score 4):

The Drupal 7 database layer uses PDO which prior to PHP 5.3.7 did not support MySQL with SSL.

Assuming you're using PHP 5.3.7 or later there is a [patch available](http://drupal.org/files/issues/726192-arbitrary-pdo-options-attributes.patch) for Drupal to allow "arbitrary PDO options" to be used, which would include the ability to specify an SSL option.

See [this discussion](http://drupal.org/node/726192) for a fair bit more information and links to the issues on php.net.

**EDIT**

For Drupal 6 you can change the `mysql_connect()` line in includes/database.mysql.inc to:

```
$connection = @mysql_connect($url['host'], $url['user'], $url['pass'], TRUE, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
```

Although you should really turn this into a patch and apply it to the includes/database.mysql.inc file as hacking core is never a good idea.

Comment: Did find the php.net link a bit after I posed the question. Thanks a ton. So for those stuck on debian(with a default php version 5.3.3) and Drupal 7, I assume that there is no way to connect to mysql using ssl.

Comment: @L0neRanger It does look that way yeah :/